# jquery, resize a canvas without scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I was trying to put a canvas in a container. I wanted the canvas to have the same size as the container. To do this I used JQuery, however, this turned out to scale my canvas. This was not my intention, especially because I draw after resizing. Doing seemingly the same thing in good old fashion JavaScript gives me the expected result.

I personally did not expect the JQuery result and it took some time before I figured out the problem. Does anybody know why they opted for this implementation and why it gives a different result? I hope by sharing this I can save some people a lot of time!

Thanks for anybody willing to research this further of fix this!

Here is some example code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Canvas resizing</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #container1{
            background-color: green;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 50px auto;
        }

        #container2{
            background-color: red;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            margin: 50px auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container1">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="container2">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function draw (canvas) {
            var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.lineWidth = 5;
            context.rect(25,25,50,50);
            context.stroke();
        }

        $(document).ready(function () {
            //javascript
            var container = document.getElementById('container1');
            var canvas = container.childNodes[1];
            canvas.width = 100;
            canvas.height = 100;
            draw(canvas);

            //jquery
            var container = $('#container2');
            var canvas = container.children()[0];
            $(canvas).width(100);
            $(canvas).height(100);
            draw(canvas);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery width and height methods are shorthand aliases for setting the CSS width and height properties. Sizing a canvas using CSS causes the scaled, distorted look you're seeing. Your pure javascript version of the code is setting the width and height attributes of the canvas element. To achieve the same in jQuery you can use:

```
$(canvas).prop('width', 100)
$(canvas).prop('height', 100)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d43xk4jm/)

Comment: Yep, change the canvas element size rather than the CSS size. I might just note that changing the canvas element's size will clear any existing content on the canvas so resize before drawing or alternatively redraw the content after resizing. Upvote.

Comment: thanks! Is resizing the canvas a fast way to clear it? As far as i'm aware clearing a rectangle in the canvas is the fastest way. Can you control the viewport yourself using the context?